# remove lengend title created by add_trace in R plotly

Tags: r, plot, plotly, tidyverse

I would like to know how to do the following:

1. remove or rename the legend title (see below in red)
2. remove the entire legend created by the function add_trace from the package plotly. As this doesn't seem to work through the conventional way with `showlegend = FALSE` [image: remove/edit the legend title]

data + code

```
library(tidyverse)
library(plotly)

Strat <- structure(list(GS.Open = c(200.600006, 200.220001, 198.429993, 
                                    199.050003, 203.539993, 203.399994, 208.339996, 210.899994, 210.850006, 
                                    212.199997, 213.75), GS.High = c(203.320007, 200.669998, 200, 
                                                                     203.949997, 204.899994, 208.440002, 213.169998, 214.220001, 215.130005, 
                                                                     214.089996, 214.809998), GS.Low = c(197.820007, 198.070007, 197.899994, 
                                                                                                         198.100006, 202, 201.5, 207.600006, 210.399994, 210.850006, 210.850006, 
                                                                                                         209.100006), GS.Close = c(200.720001, 198.850006, 199.050003, 
                                                                                                                                   203.729996, 204.080002, 208.110001, 211.880005, 213.990005, 213.589996, 
                                                                                                                                   213.229996, 209.679993), GS.Volume = c(6494900, 6460200, 5892900, 
                                                                                                                                                                          7851000, 7147100, 8025700, 9039400, 6618900, 5846600, 5306300, 
                                                                                                                                                                          6423200), GS.Adjusted = c(162.160843, 160.65007, 160.811646, 
                                                                                                                                                                                                    164.59259, 164.875336, 168.131134, 171.177002, 172.881592, 172.558426, 
                                                                                                                                                                                                    172.267532, 169.399551), date = c("2007-01-03", "2007-01-04", 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                      "2007-01-05", "2007-01-08", "2007-01-09", "2007-01-10", "2007-01-11", 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                      "2007-01-12", "2007-01-16", "2007-01-17", "2007-01-18"), level = c(200, 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                         200, 200, 200, 200, 200, 200, 200, 200, 200, 200), level2 = c(250, 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                       250, 250, 250, 250, 250, 250, 250, 250, 250, 250), points = -5:5), row.names = c("2007-01-03", 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                        "2007-01-04", "2007-01-05", "2007-01-08", "2007-01-09", "2007-01-10", 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                        "2007-01-11", "2007-01-12", "2007-01-16", "2007-01-17", "2007-01-18"
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                       ), class = "data.frame")
Plot_Points <- Strat %>% 
  filter((points <= -3 | points >= 3))

i <- list(line = list(color = '#6b998b'))
d <- list(line = list(color = '#996b6b'))


p <- Strat %>% plot_ly(x = ~date, type="candlestick",
                       open = ~GS.Open, close = ~GS.Close,
                       high = ~GS.High, low = ~GS.Low,
                       increasing = i, decreasing = d) %>% 
  add_trace(x = ~Plot_Points$date, y = ~Plot_Points$GS.Close, color = ~Plot_Points$points, type = "scatter",
            mode = 'markers',
            marker = list(size = 8, opacity = 0.8), 
            showlegend = FALSE,
            hovertemplate = paste("Signal: %{marker.color:f}", "<extra></extra>")) %>% # marker.color:,.0f round
  layout(
    showlegend = FALSE,
    plot_bgcolor='#343E48',
    paper_bgcolor='#343E48',
    font = list(color = 'grey')
    # hovermode = "x unified"
  )
p
```

Comment: After your call for `layout` add `%>% colorbar(title = '')`

Comment: Can you change the `add_trace` to `add_trace(x = ~Plot_Points$date, y = ~Plot_Points$GS.Close, color = ~factor(Plot_Points$points), type = "scatter",
            mode = 'markers',
            marker = list(size = 8, opacity = 0.8), 
            name = "",
           
            hovertemplate = paste("Signal: %{marker.color:f}", "<extra></extra>"))`